# What is the world-sheet picture of high energy open string scattering?

Tags: string-theory

Following Gross-Manes paper (which came right after Gross-Mende), the planar one-loop amplitude (the annulus) is dominated by the region in moduli space where the radius of the annulus shrinks to a point, i.e. it looks like the tree amplitude. Does anyone know if this generalizes for to all-loops?

Comment: Could you please give the full bibliographical reference of the paper or a link to it on the web?

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot for your interest in this question. The link to the paper is http://inspirehep.net/record/277712